# Wordpress PHP 7 with htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I have a website on a webserver that is using php 5.6 (joomla 1.5). I also want to set up another website based on wordpress. I managed to make it work, however some wordpress extensions require php 7. I decided to add `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php` in `htaccess` file placed in directory with wordpress.
It seems to be working as `phpinfo()` in that dir shows the desired php version (7.4). Unfortunately wordpress stopped working. It throws such error: `Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.`

However if I changed php version to 7.4 through `cpanel` it works flawlessly (however joomla website stops working). Is there any easy way to fix this?

Comment: No one should be running PHP5.6 anymore nor should any site still be running on Joomla1.5  Time to set up a brand new environment with a current and stable version of PHP and Joomla and start moving what you have into the new environment and fixing the new environment as you go.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

- The Default PHP version has been changed to PHP 7.4. Now, WordPress works but Joomla doesn't.

**Solution:**
You would need a MultiPHP configuration on CPanel.

1 - Keep the Joomla site with PHP 5.6

2 - Keep the WordPress site with PHP 7.4

Reference:
https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/software/multiphp-manager-for-cpanel/

Regards.
Ed.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no MultiPHP in my CPanel. Do you have any idea why it is not working when i change htaccess so that specific dir is forced to use different version of PHP than default?

Comment: Try using PHP Handler through Htaccess. 
https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/adding-handlers-to-change-your-php-version